# Verify tautology using Quick Method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How can I verify the following statement whether it's tautology using `Quick method`?

```
((P ˄ Q) →R) →(¬R → P)
```

Comment: Try to find a truth assignment that falsify the consequent and verify the antecedent.

Comment: But can you explain me that how the `Quick Method` works? I don't understand that

Comment: Maybe you have to explain us what the "Quick Method" is...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA like the way Bram28 did in the first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'Quick Method' I assume you mean something like the following:

\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
((P & \land & Q) & \rightarrow & R) & \rightarrow & (\neg & R & \rightarrow & P)\\
F_8 & F_9 & & T_2 & F_7 & F_1 & T_4 & F_6 & F_3 & F_5\\
\end{array}

(the indices indicate the order in which the truth-values were assigned)

So: I tried to make the statement False, found that in order to do so had to set $P$ and $R$ to $False$ ... but otherwise found no contradiction. In other words, it is possible to make the statement false, as long as I set $P$ and $R$ to $False$ ($Q$ can be either $True$ or $False$, since given that $P$ is $False$, $P \land Q$ has to be $False$ as well, and that will make $(P \land Q) \rightarrow R$ $True$, as desired).

So, the statement is *not* a tautology

Comment: Yes I was looking for this. But i still have one confusion, why Q can be either true or false?

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar Because $P$ being false automatically makes $P \land Q$ false, regardless of the value of $Q$

Comment: then in the case of (P->Q)->(Q->P), what will be their values?

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar New question -> new post!  But you should really try this on your own first!

Comment: hahaha ok .. Your answer is appreciable :)